# On Windows running node.js executable has strange process.stdout behavior

Tags: node.js, windows, stdout

It looks like this is probably related to quirks of the system I am using to run my node scripts on Windows. I try to keep the dev environment really basic on Windows because the Windows boxes that I have get wiped periodically as is the nature of Windows.

So I'm using this mintty 2.6.2 that came with the Git for Windows installer.

I have a program that needs to read a comically large XML file, this is the readline code I use to parse it.

```
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2]),
    output: process.stdout,
    console: false
});
```

Take note also that the script has `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of it.

The program consumes the content of the `process.argv[2]` file on a line by line basis with the `line` event.

If I run this program like `./program.js args`, `argv[2]`'s contents DO NOT make it onto stdout.

If I run this program like `node ./program.js args`, `argv[2]`'s contents DO make it onto stdout.

I can simply comment out the `output` field or replace it with something like `require('stream-blackhole')()`, but I'm really curious why the stdout behavior is so weird on this environment.

Oh also, by the way I get `stdout is not a tty` when running with the `node` command line call, when I try to redirect the output anywhere.